# Are there any free offline eventlog explorer?

Tags: log4net, event-log

I want to have some to tool to explore our eventlogs.
There are few developers, so it would be nice if this tool is free.

Log4net(btw : we use log4net to log in our applications) dashboard ([http://www.l4ndash.com/Default.aspx][1]) looks very nice, but it is paid and online and it's a problem.

Has anyone know  some interesting tool ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For log4net there is this one that is free:

http://log2console.codeplex.com/

Personally I use [Log4View](http://www.log4view.org/home.html) which is not free, but not that expensive either.